# Angular component for select with custom input

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I'm creating an Angular widget which combines a dropdown with a custom input. I've made it generic and am preparing a blogpost explaining my setup, and would love to get a review before I do so.

The most basic *usage* of this component would look like this:

```xml
<select-with-custom-input
  baseOptions="['one', 'two', 'three']"
  customOption="other, specify..."
  selectLabel="Pick something"
  placeholder="enter a value"
  required="true"
  classForLabel="form-label"
  classForSelect="form-control"
  classForInput="form-control mt-3"
  [(ngModel)]="myModelProperty"
></select-with-custom-input>
```

See [this StackBlitz.com example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-55ctpf) for a live demo.

You will see a dropdown, and if you select the `customOption` you get a chance to fill out a custom value in an input field. The end result of the component should be *one* string value: either one of the base options, or the custom text you provided.

The component's code is inspired on [the default `ControlValueAccessor` from the Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts), and that's what I'd love to get feedback on:

```typescript
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-with-custom-input',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: SelectWithCustomInputComponent,
    multi: true,
  }],
  styles: [],
  template: `
    <label for="selectForBaseOptions"
          [class]="classForLabel"
          *ngIf="selectLabel">
      {{ selectLabel }}
    </label>
    <select [class]="classForSelect"
            id="selectForBaseOptions"
            [required]="required"
            [disabled]="_isDisabled"
            (blur)="onTouched()"
            (ngModelChange)="_selectChanged($event)"
            [(ngModel)]="_selectedOption">
      <option value="" [selected]="_selectedOption === ''"></option>
      <option *ngFor="let option of baseOptions"
              [selected]="_selectedOption === option"
              [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </option>
      <option [value]="customOption" [selected]="_isCustomOptionSelected">
        {{ customOption }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text"
          id="inputForCustomOption"
          [class]="classForInput"
          *ngIf="_isCustomOptionSelected"
          [required]="required"
          [disabled]="_isDisabled"
          [placeholder]="placeholder"
          (blur)="onTouched()"
          (ngModelChange)="_customValueChanged($event)"
          [(ngModel)]="_customInput">
  `,
})
export class SelectWithCustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() selectLabel = '';
  @Input() baseOptions = [];
  @Input() customOption = 'Other...';
  @Input() placeholder = '';
  @Input() required = false;

  // Allow frameworks like Bootstrap to style individual elements easily:
  @Input() classForLabel = '';
  @Input() classForInput = '';
  @Input() classForSelect = '';

  _selectedOption = '';
  _customInput = '';
  _isCustomOptionSelected = false;
  _isDisabled = false;

  private onChange = (_: any) => { };
  private onTouched = (_: any) => { };

  _selectChanged(value: string): void {
    this._isCustomOptionSelected = value === this.customOption;

    this.onChange(this._isCustomOptionSelected
      ? this._customInput
      : value);
  }

  _customValueChanged(value: string): void {
    this.onChange(value);
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? '' : value;

    this._isCustomOptionSelected = normalizedValue
      ? this.customOption === normalizedValue || !this.baseOptions.includes(normalizedValue)
      : false;

    if (this._isCustomOptionSelected) {
      this._selectedOption = this.customOption;
      this._customInput = normalizedValue;
    } else {
      this._selectedOption = normalizedValue;
      this._customInput = '';
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

I also have a test suite with component integration tests to check if the behavior is as expected, that should give (near) 100% statement coverage. If you have any comments on this spec it would also be appreciated:

```typescript
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { SelectWithCustomInputComponent } from './select-with-custom-input.component';

describe('SelectWithCustomInputComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SelectWithCustomInputComponent>;
  let component: SelectWithCustomInputComponent;
  let nativeElement: HTMLElement;
  let select: HTMLSelectElement;
  let latestValueReceivedFromComponent;
  let hasOnTouchedBeenCalled = false;

  // Has an *ngIf so need to get this element as late as possible
  const getInputElement = () => nativeElement.querySelector('input');

  function makeFixtureStable() {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ SelectWithCustomInputComponent ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SelectWithCustomInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.registerOnChange(val => latestValueReceivedFromComponent = val);
    component.registerOnTouched(_ => hasOnTouchedBeenCalled = true);
    nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    select = nativeElement.querySelector('select');
  });

  it('should see null as empty string', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.writeValue(null);
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(select.value).toEqual('');
  }));

  it('should see undefined as empty string', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.writeValue(undefined);
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(select.value).toEqual('');
  }));

  it('should see empty string as empty string', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.writeValue('');
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(select.value).toEqual('');
  }));

  it('should be able to select a base option', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['option 1', 'option 2'];
    component.writeValue('option 2');
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(select.value).toEqual('option 2');
  }));

  it('should not show the input if a base option is selected', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['option 1'];
    component.writeValue('option 1');
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(getInputElement()).toBeFalsy();
  }));

  it('should be able to load custom option', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['option 1'];
    component.writeValue('my custom text');
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(getInputElement().value).toEqual('my custom text');
  }));

  it('should propagate disabled state to select', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.setDisabledState(true);
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(select.disabled).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should propagate disabled state to input', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.writeValue('my custom text');
    component.setDisabledState(true);
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(getInputElement().disabled).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should propagate placeholder state to input', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.placeholder = 'enter your value';
    component.writeValue('my custom text');
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(getInputElement().getAttribute('placeholder')).toEqual('enter your value');
  }));

  it('should register change of option', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['A', 'B'];
    makeFixtureStable();
    select.value = 'B';
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(latestValueReceivedFromComponent).toEqual('B');
  }));

  it('should register change to provided custom option', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['A', 'B'];
    component.customOption = 'Custom!';
    makeFixtureStable();
    select.value = 'Custom!';
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(latestValueReceivedFromComponent).toEqual('');
  }));

  it('should register value entered in input', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['A'];
    makeFixtureStable();
    select.value = 'Other...';
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(latestValueReceivedFromComponent).toEqual('');
    getInputElement().value = 'custom text';
    getInputElement().dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    expect(latestValueReceivedFromComponent).toEqual('custom text');
  }));

  it('should fire touched handler on select blur', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['A'];
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(hasOnTouchedBeenCalled).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should fire touched handler on input blur', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.baseOptions = ['A'];
    makeFixtureStable();
    select.value = 'Other...';
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    makeFixtureStable();
    hasOnTouchedBeenCalled = false;
    getInputElement().dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
    makeFixtureStable();
    expect(hasOnTouchedBeenCalled).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

PS. This was built with an Angular 7 CLI project in mind.